# Constant listener for Boolean - Java Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, boolean

In my android app, I'm trying to check whether a boolean has changed and if it has then do something. But it's not constantly checking it. I believe I need a listener, but I'am unaware on how to structure it or where to put it. I've looked online and can really only find `onClick`s etc, no boolean ones.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public boolean gameStartTouch = false;
public boolean titleVisible = true;
/*
public boolean isJumping = false;
public boolean isGrounded = false;
*/

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_main);    
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int eventaction = event.getAction();

    switch (eventaction) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    if (gameStartTouch == false) {

        gameStartTouch = true;
        titleVisible = false;
    }
    break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and this is what needs to go in the listener:

```
ImageView titleView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.titleImg);
ImageView startNotifView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.startNotifImg);

if (titleVisible == false) {    
    titleView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    startNotifView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
} else {
    titleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    startNotifView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Thanks in advance. I  couldn't find much info on it for these circumstances specifically.

Comment: Why aren't you just performing the functionality you want to perform when you switch it? Like instead of just doing `gameStartTouch = true` do `private void handleGameStartTouch(boolean start){ gameStartTouch = start; // add in the WHAT NEEDS TO GO IN THE LISTENER STUFF }`

Comment: I wasn't aware that was a thing. So functions can go in switch statements?

Comment: I will write a more thorough answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do some modifying to your code, manage it like so

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int eventaction = event.getAction();

    switch (eventaction) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        titleView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        startNotifView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I would put your `findViewById()` calls in onCreate to avoid unnecessary resource fetching. The only thing I see is that you are only actually switching your booleans once. Is there any other time you plan to reset gameStartTouch to false and titleVisible to true after the first touch?

Comment: Derp. That makes sense. Thanks a lot! Nah, i wont be resetting or anything. But how do I call the image view lines from the onCreate in the new function? Do i assign them into variables?

Comment: @fire_head if you aren't changing them I can simplify this a lot. When I get home I will update it for you. Sheraz is headed in the right direction with his comment below

Comment: @fire_head see update for a start. No need for all of the booleans since it only has a single purpose and only gets called once without reset

Answer (score 0):

@fire_head you can simply declare `titleView` and `startNotifView` as your class private members. Initialize them in `onCreate` method like this:

```
ImageView titleView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.titleImg); 
ImageView startNotifView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.starting);
```

and access them in `handleGameStartTouch` method.

Sorry, I had to post it as an answer as I couldn't comment on the answer above.